# Nginx proxy_cache_lock in multiple locations

Tags: nginx, nginx-cache

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        ...

        location /good { 
            proxy_cache mycache;
            proxy_cache_key $arg_cachekey;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 1h;
            proxy_cache_lock on;
            proxy_cache_lock_timeout 20m;
            proxy_cache_lock_age 20m;
            ...
            (upstream returning 200 with the content)
        }

        location /bad { 
            proxy_cache mycache;
            proxy_cache_key $arg_cachekey;
            proxy_cache_lock on;
            proxy_cache_lock_timeout 20m;
            proxy_cache_lock_age 20m;
            ...
            (upstream returning 404)
        }
    }
}
```

The cache is empty. Requesting:

```
GET /good?cachekey=123
```

after a short time while `/good` upstream is responding with the content, requesting:

```
GET /bad?cachekey=123
```

Should request on `/bad` location wait until `/good` retrieves cache and `/bad` respond with 200? If no, how to achieve it?